# I need help I face problem in Execution failed for task ':react-native-navigation:compileReactNative57DebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: navigation, react-native

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-navigation:compileReactNative57DebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5s
30 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 29 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command in your project terminal: `gradle build --warning-mode=all`
to see what exactly the deprecated features are.
It will provide you with he detailed description on the issues with links. Follow he guidelines provided in the links.
Also make sure your react-navigation version is compatible with react-native version.
Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks a lot the issue is resolved by increasing the react-native version from "react-native": "^0.49.0", to "react-native": "^0.57.0" in package.json file and run command npm install in the terminal.